# facebook like button not working incorrect meta data but data is correct

Tags: facebook, facebook-like, lint

Im currently using the fb url linter and can see that everything is there correctly, however when a user likes the page it misses key information.

the linter is also stating there is missing content, however it also shows that all tags are there as well. is there anything wrong with my code ?

this is the result on the facebook url linter

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fdev.murchison-hume.com%2FProducts%2FSuperlative-Liquid-Hand-Soap%2FCoriander-Superlative-Liquid-Hand-Soap-Refill

it has conflicting messages stating things dont exist, when they obviously do as they are outlined below the error messages...
any help greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Recheck your type contents. The first error is telling you that you don't own the object type. For custom objects, usually you need to pass in

```
<meta property="og:type" content="MY_APP_NAMESPACE:product"/>
```

If that fails, og:type errors usually comes up when you fail to setup your objects correctly in your open graph settings (at developers.facebook.com).

I suspect that fixing the first error will make the others disappear.